# mod_rewrite rules for my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have these rules on my site:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(support|about-us|profile|support|features|videos|terms-of-service|about-us|signup|media|includes|modules|cgi-bin|templates|xmlrpc|language|libraries|plugins|administrator|component|images|dev|data)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([a-z0-9\-]+)/[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/(.*)$ https://$1.example.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

#

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %1 !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(support|about-us|profile|support|features|newserver|videos|about-us|terms-of-service|signup|component|includes|media|cgi-bin|templates|xmlrpc|language|modules|libraries|plugins|administrator|images(/.*))$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 # Externally redirect all www hostnames to non-www hostnames
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*)www\.(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*)example\.com
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%3example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I added these below to redirect these types: https://example.com/firstnamelastname?mv=0 etc

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mv=[0-4]$
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ https://$1.example.com/? [L,R]
```

However I cannot get these to redirect https://example.com/firstnamelastname

If i remove the Query string from the last 3 lines then If i would click on features link on my website It would redirect to https://features.example.com which is what the rules at the top are preventing.

Can anyone assist with this.

Comment: Can you clarify what your previous rules are doing?

Comment: The previous rules are supposed to be redirect all requests for https://firstnamelastname.example.com/features to https://remembered.com/features etc.

Comment: It is not clear to me. Can you clarify with some examples.